# excel popup button to ask how much money to add to an existing cell with an existing amount

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

Let me rephrase my question. I am making an excel worksheet to close our registers. My worksheet counts all coins and loose dollar bills. When entering checks, i would like to have a button that saves all entries on sheet2 and adds them up on cell C2. Is it possible to have a button in excel that (when pushed) would ask to enter an amount, and the new amount would be added to a cell with an existing amount.

Example: "C2" has the value of $4.50. "D2" has the "Add Money" button. When button is pushed, it would ask to enter an amount. Once you enter the amount ($12.75) and press "ENTER", "C2" will update itself to $17.25.

Also, i would like to all entries to be save on the sheet2, so we can have a record of each new entry.

Update on 9/1/19 - For those who want a button to add check entries, this is what I ended up using. This code (mainly thanks to Marcucciboy2) adds all the checks into a cell in sheet 1, but stores all the check info on sheet 2.

```
    Sub Checks()

    Dim CheckNumber As String, CheckNumberlr As Long
    CheckNumber = InputBox("Check Number", "Please Enter")
    If CheckNumber = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        CheckNumberlr = Worksheets("Checks").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Worksheets("Checks").Range("A" & CheckNumberlr).Value = CheckNumber

    End If

    Dim CheckDate As String, CheckDatelr As Long
    CheckDate = InputBox("Check Date", "Please Enter", Date)
    If CheckDate = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        CheckDatelr = Worksheets("Checks").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Worksheets("Checks").Range("B" & CheckDatelr).Value = CheckDate

    End If

    Dim CheckAmount As String, CheckAmountlr As Long
    CheckAmount = InputBox("Enter Check Amount", "Please Enter")
    If CheckAmount = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        CheckAmountlr = Worksheets("Checks").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Worksheets("Checks").Range("C" & CheckAmountlr).Value = CheckAmount

    End If

    Dim OrderNumber As String, OrderNumberlr As Long
    OrderNumber = InputBox("If Available, Enter Order Number", "Please Enter")
    If OrderNumber = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        OrderNumberlr = Worksheets("Checks").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Worksheets("Checks").Range("D" & OrderNumberlr).Value = OrderNumber

    End If
    End Sub
```

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: A quick internet search yielded [this](https://web.stanford.edu/group/ttsclasses/cgi-bin/techietips/?p=1725). Hope that helps.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your bonus?

Comment: My guess is he wants someone to answer how to solve that secondary problem too. As in a "bonus question"..?

Comment: @Bear I understand the concept but not the bonus question itself

Comment: Gotcha, he might be talking about how to link the sheets together. That's my take on it anyway.

Comment: Hello Bear. Thanks for the help. This option only adds a comment. Im looking for a button that adds all entries, saves all entries on sheet2, and adds them up on cell C2 as you are entering them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here’s how to connect the macro to a button](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/assign-a-macro-to-a-form-or-a-control-button-d58edd7d-cb04-4964-bead-9c72c843a283)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim val As Long
    val = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Amount", Type:=1)

    Range("C43").Value = Range("C43").Value + val
End Sub
```

Comment: This can be improved upon by using `Application.Inputbox` and validating the entry. +1 regardless

Comment: @urdearboy You're right, I kind of phoned it in for this one

Comment: Thank you  Marcucciboy2. This is somewhat similar to what im looking for. Although it doesn't quite work. I will see if i can work with the help that you provided. Thank you.

Comment: @urdearboy, Where would i insert the Application.Inputbox, or what line should it replace on  Marcucciboy2 example?

Comment: @HenryNavarro describe how it doesn't work. I made a little update that may help

Comment: Take a look at this image. Hope it helps. ( https://ibb.co/dd403p ) By clicking the "Checks" button (on cell D43), a pop up appears and asks for an amount. You enter the amount and press Enter. The pop up disappears and It then updates a cell (C43) by adding whatever amount you entered into the popup. See this other image ( https://ibb.co/hZW53p ). Note: These images are photo shopped. :)

Comment: Also, if possible, all entries would be save on Sheet2, on column A.

Comment: @HenryNavarro you still haven’t described the problem you’re having

Comment: https://ibb.co/i8Z8PU - After pressing on the button, it just says Syntax Error.

Comment: @HenryNavarro turns out `input` is a reserved word in vba, so I renamed it to `val` and now it should work

Comment: This works now. Thank you. One last question. If i needed to enter multiple entries (check number, check date, check amount & order number) to be saved on Sheet2, how can that be done? I tried to modify your code to ask me for all of that already, but it doesn't save anything after the first entry, and it doesn't record it into the second row on sheet2. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @HenryNavarro why not open up another question? I think a question like that someone would be willing to answer